Functional form of dihedral energy term in molecular mechanics: why always cosine?
As far as I can tell from looking into the most popular reference texts, it seems that the dihedral energy term in a molecular mechanics forcefield always uses cosine function (more specifically a linear combination of cos functions). Are there any specific reasons that combination of cosines is the function of choice as opposed to sine functions, or a combination of sine and cosines? Or is this just a matter of convention. Hopefully I am not missing something obvious!

I'm guessing because steric clash is the greatest when dihedral angle is 0 and cosine  has max at 0.

You can use either since they can be transformed: $\cos(\alpha+\beta)=\cos(a)\cos(\beta)+\sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta)$, so that $\sin(\alpha) = \cos(\alpha+\pi/2)$

Both the phase and periodicity can be adjusted using constants within the formula, so there is no meaningful difference to using cosine or sine (provided those constants are taken into consideration).

Also, note that proper and improper dihedrals are usually defined in  MD, I do not know if they follow different functional forms for their Force Field parameters

The MD tag at MMSE has 500+ questions in less than 4.5 years. If you don't get a satisfactory answer here, you can try there. The MD tag here barely has 100 questions.
